# Сумма значений нескольких строк из данных двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос, суммирование

У меня есть две таблицы:

1-я таблица `articles`

```
artice_id
user_login
title 
article
```

2-я таблица `params`

```
id
article_id 
liked
```

Один пользователь может написать несколько статей, соответственно будет несколько строк в обеих таблицах. Также и лайки могут быть на всех статьях. Как мне получить сумму лайков для какого-либо конкретного пользователя в одном запросе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(prm.liked)
FROM
  articles art
  JOIN params prm ON (
    art.article_id = prm.article_id
  )
WHERE
  art.user_login = .....
```

А вот так для всех пользователей

```
SELECT
  art.user_login,
  SUM(prm.liked)
FROM
  articles art
  JOIN params prm ON (
    art.article_id = prm.article_id
  )
GROUP BY
  art.user_login
```

Comment: А art и prm это сокращения от полных названий таблиц или новые имена?

Comment: @VladZaev Это алиасы таблиц, которые определяются прямо в запросе

Comment: или все значения подряд?

Comment: @VladZaev не понял вопроса

Comment: ну всмысле запрос идет в php в переменной $getLiked = ... Как потом вывести то, что получил из запроса? Я пробую через $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getLiked) и после echo $result, но не получается...